# github api does not work in git bash, but in cmd it does

Tags: git, github, cmd, git-bash

Hello when I am testing the github api in Git Bash everything works fine until I use this command:

```
curl -i -u myuser https://api.github.com/users/myuser
```

but when I do it in the windows cmd it works perfectly, it instantly asks me for the password,i already tried uninstalling and installing git but it doesn't work.

Here I show what is happening
https://www.loom.com/share/8aabb02719424117ad0f70ba40ce5234

Comment: Could you describe what actually happens when things don’t work? Do you get an error message?

Comment: it does not send me any error, it is as if it was loading, but in cmd it is instantaneous

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tested it in a git bash session:

```sh
vonc@vclp MINGW64 ~/git/git (master)
$ curl -i -u VonC https://api.github.com/users/VonC
Enter host password for user 'VonC':
...
{
  "login": "VonC",
  ...
}
```

It does work.

But my %PATH% (before typing bash) is, from a CMD:

```sh
C:\Users\vonc\git\git>where curl
C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin\curl.exe
C:\Windows\System32\curl.exe
```

So I use the `curl` from the Git for Windows, *before* the Windows one.

Based on your video, and "[cURL won't prompt me for password using GitHub API](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59062139/6309)", try adding `winpty`:

```
winpty curl -u <me> https://api.github.com/users/<me>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, the truth is I am new to git and this world and I do not understand, I do not know if I explained well what my situation is, so attach a short video in the question

Comment: @IvanRaulSanchezDiaz I see. I have edited the answer accordingly, with a possible solution.